# Rails AR - validating that parents of join table have same parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following classes:

```
class Account
  has_many :payment_methods
  has_many :orders

class PaymentMethod
  belongs_to :account, inverse_of: :payment_methods
  has_many :payments

class Order
  belongs_to :account, inverse_of: :orders
  has_many :payments

class Payment
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :payments
  belongs_to :payment_method, inverse_of: :payments
```

I have an order form that creates a payment as a child.  That payment also has an associated payment_method.  The idea is that placing an order will build the order and payment objects, the order will call payment.process (below), the payment will call a charge method on the payment_method object, and if all that passes, the payment and order are saved.  Still with me?

Ok, so I need to validate at the payment level that both order and payment_method have the same parent (account), otherwise it needs to fail validation and not try to process.  I have this method in the payment class:

```
def process
  charge = payment_method.charge amount
  self.is_paid = true
  self.transaction_id = charge.id
rescue Exception => e
  # handle exception
end
```

And this validation:

```
def payment_method_belongs_to_account
  if payment_method and payment_method.account != order.account
    # add error
  end
end
```

I'm running into a few issues.

1. I am calling payment_method.charge before the payment is validated. 
   I can solve this by explicitly calling self.validate inside the `payment.process` method before calling `payment_method.charge`, but that leads to #2 below.
2. If I attempt to call `validate` on the payment object, I get an exception because `payment.order` is nil.  The order hasn't been saved yet, so the reference inside the child object (payment) hasn't been set up.

It seems like solving for #2 is the easiest solution.  I'm not sure why the reference from the child (payment) to the parent (order) isn't getting set up.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my own question.  I'll leave this here in case it can help someone else.

Adding this to my Order class fixed the problem:

```
has_many :payments, inverse_of: :order
```

It seems like that should happen automatically, but obviously not.